# Confusion about Lemma for Breadth-first search (BFS) proof of correctness

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, breadth-first-search

I'm working my way through the graph section of *Introduction to Algorithms* by CLRS (3E,4E) and I came across the following proof:

**3E: Lemma 22.2**

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed or undirected graph, and suppose that BFS is run on $G$ from a given source vertex $s \in V$. Then upon termination, for each vertex $v \in V$, the value $v.d$ computed by BFS satisfies $v.d \geq \delta(s,v)$.

**4E: Lemma 20.2**

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed or undirected graph, and suppose that BFS is run on $G$ from a given source vertex $s \in V$. Then, for each vertex $v \in V$, the value $v.d$ computed by BFS satisfies $v.d \geq \delta(s,v)$ at all times, including at termination.

**Proof:** We use induction on the number of ENQUEUE operations. Our inductive hypothesis is that $v.d \geq \delta(s,v)$ for all $v \in V$

The basis of the induction is the situation immediately after enqueuing $s$ in line 9 of BFS. The inductive hypothesis holds here, because $s.d = 0 = \delta(s,s)$ and $v.d = \infty \geq \delta(s,v)$ for all $v \in V - \{s\}$.

For the inductive step, consider a white vertex $v$ that is discovered during the search from a vertex $u$. The inductive hypothesis implies that $u.d \geq \delta(s, u)$. From the assignment performed by line 15 and from Lemma 22.1, we obtain
$$v.d = u.d + 1 \geq \delta(s, u) + 1 \geq \delta(s, v)$$

Vertex $v$ is then enqueued, and it is never enqueued again because it is also grayed and the then clause of lines 14–17 is executed only for white vertices. Thus, the value of $v.d$ never changes again, and the inductive hypothesis is maintained.

I have a few questions about this proof.

First, how does this actually prove the Lemma? It seems all we have proved is that $v.d \geq \delta(s,v)$ for all $v \in V$ after $n$ ENQUEUE operations.

Second, the fact that $v$ is never enqueued again isn't part of the inductive hypothesis, so why do the authors write as if it is?

The inductive hypothesis can maybe be rephrased as "$v.d \geq \delta(s,v)$ for all $v \in V$ after n ENQUEUE operations". We could then change the last paragraph to something like this:
"After vertex $v$ is enqueued, it is never enqueued again because it is also grayed and the then clause of lines 14–17 is executed only for white vertices. Thus, the value of $v.d$ never changes again. Since every vertex is ENQUEUED at most once and the value $v.d$ never changes once it is set, after termination it follows that $v.d \geq \delta(s,v)$ for all $v \in V$"

Comment: Well, $n$ is the size of $V$ and since each vertex is enqueued at most once, after $n$ steps, all of $V$ is handled. The induction thus proves that the statement holds for all of $V$.